# sum all row from 2 column and use select to display two column

Tags: php, mysql

**example**

```
|like |comment|
|user1|asd    |
|user2|awe    |
|user3|aqw    |
|user4|atr    |
|user5|axc    |
|user6|azw    |
|user7|       |
```

i have two column and what i wanted to do is to sum all rows inside those column  and fetch the two column but i dont have any idea on how to do it in a query in sql.

**result**

```
|like |comment|
| 7   |   6   |
```

i tried queering it but i can only fetch 1 column i dont know how to do it with two column..

```
function countpostcomment($puid){
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(pc_comment) FROM pcomment WHERE post_uid = '$puid'";
$stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array("0"));
$active_data = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
return $active_data;
}
```

here is my sample query i haven't tested the whole function only the select cause i dont know if i need to use array or not..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you simply want:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as likes, COUNT(pc_comment) as comments
FROM pcomment
WHERE post_uid = '$puid';
```

`COUNT(*)` counts the number of rows (7 in this case).  `COUNT(<column name>)` counts the number of non-NULL values in the column (6 in this case).

Comment: if this works do i need to use an array to fetch the data or not?

Comment: @AlfieGaring . . . This returns one row with two columns.  An array seems like overkill.